# How to handle partial zero dates (ie. 2010-04-00) in Classic ASP/VBScript?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, vbscript, date

I have a MySQL-table in which I store, among other things, dates in a normal "date" field. Some dates however are incomplete with either the day or both the day and month missing, substituted with double zeroes, which I believe is the "mysql way to do it". Some examples:

2007-04-03 - 3 April 2007
   2006-03-00 - Mars 2006
   2008-00-00 - 2008

Only problem is, when I try to receive dates that are "incomplete" with double zeros in classic asp, it won't output it since it won't recognize it as either a date or string.

What I'd like to do is simply this, outputting the date just like a string:

```
Set RecSet = Connect.Execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
    Response.Write RecSet("mydate")
Set RecSet = nothing
```

I know that I might solve this easily by simply changing the field from date to varchar, but I don't know if there's any side effects to this, like problems when comparing dates in varchar-fields with dates in dates-fields, or comparing varchar-dates with eachother in the SQL query.

Therefore I'd like to keep storing my dates in a date-field, but since I can't output them I have a problem.

So, anyone know how I can handle (partially) zero-dates in ASP?

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the 00s with 01s in your select statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE(date_column,'-00','-01') AS formatted_date
FROM mytable
```

Comment: I thought about that, but realized that the application won't know if it's an "incomplete" date or if it's meant to be eg. 1997-03-01 (instead of 1997-03-00). My table contains both dates like 2007-01-01 and 2007-00-00. Hmm.. but, there might be a string-date converter in mysql, I'll check into that...